# Не выполняется сохранение

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Всем привет. Есть вопрос.

При нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить", вместо того чтобы сохранять, начинает думать. В чем проблема?  По этой ссылке сервер: http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/498531d1425906527

Исходник: http://dropmefiles.com/s7MjF

Comment: В консоли что?

Comment: извините,не понял вопроса.

Comment: В консоли браузера есть какие-нибудь ошибки?

Comment: Работаю в PHPstorm,server.php и js лежат в оlной папке,может я неправельно обращаюсь к файлу server.php в AJAX?

Comment: Извините,ошибся,вот что в консоле GET http://localhost:63342/server.php 404 (Not Found),я так понял не правильно указан путь,а как правильно указать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.3.36/server.php",
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(users),

        success: function(ret) {
            alert(ret);
        }

    }).done(function() {

    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: И как это должно помочь?